# How to delete entire row which has empty cell in any column, of a excel sheet containing both texts and numbers

Tags: excel, matlab, cell-array

This is my data in excel. How to delete entire row having any empty cell in any column in MATLAB. The sheet contains both texts and numbers,

```
(col1  col2 col3) 
OAS01   0   74
OAS02   0   55
OAS03   0.5 73
OAS04       24
OAS05       21
OAS06       20
OAS07   0   74
OAS08   0   52
OAS09   1   30
OAS01       81
```

I want to get output like this by deleting of entire and all rows which have any empty cell

```
(col1 col2 col3) 
OAS01 0 74 
OAS02 0 55
OAS03 0.5 73 
OAS07 0 74 
OAS08 0 52 
OAS09 1 30
```

I have tryied but not working well

```
[num, text, a] = xlsread('data.xlsx');

for i = 1:size(data,1)

if isnan(num(i,1))

    a(i,:) =[];

    num(i,:) =[];

else 
   a(i,:) =a(i,:);   
   num(i,:) =num(i,:);   
end

end

xlswrite('newfile.xlsx', a);
```

Comment: I guess you want to delete `col2`. Do you want `col3` be placed at it's place (I mean instead of `col2`)? Or you just need empty column here in `col2`?

Comment: Joe, you need to provide a bit more info and show what you have done to try solve the problem. Then you may find others more willing to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much more elegant way:

```
T = {'a','b';'','c';'d','e'}

>> T = 

'a'    'b'
''     'c'
'd'    'e'

 T(any(cellfun(@isempty,T),2),:) = []

>> T =

'a'    'b'
'd'    'e'
```

------EDIT-----

OP said it is not working, so I checked, and it is because empty cells gets loaded as NaNs by the xlsread function, so this line should fix it:

```
 [num, text, a] = xlsread('data.xlsx');
 a(any(cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x)),a),2),:) = [];
```

where a is the 3 by 3 cell that the OP loaded in.

Explanations: cellfun is largely used and well documented, in this particular case, we are interested in setting rows with NaN to [], so we are using matlab's `isnan` to detect cells which contains NaN, we then wrap the `any` function outside, which returns a boolean 1 if there is a NaN or a 0 if there isn't a NaN. The outer `any` generates the boolean index of which (0 is a row with no NaNs and 1 is a row with NaNs) we filter the data on.

Comment: @Joe please try the solution in my EDIT section and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much @gameofthrows